# How to execute 2 related Custom JSP tags with Freemarker without having SimpleSequence incompatible with java.util.List Exception

Tags: freemarker, taglib

I am using Freemarker to render my website pages. I have custom Jsp Taglib references in my pages.

I am experiencing "java.lang.ClassCastException: freemarker.template.SimpleSequence incompatible with java.util.List " while executing 2 related tags sequentially.

```
<#assign mytag=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/tld/mytaglib.tld"]/>
<@mytag.query view="home" params="query params">
    <@mytag.process maxItems=10 />
</@mytag.query>
```

The first tag mytag.query calls a query service and puts the item list to the pageContext.

```
pageContext.setAttribute("items", resultSet.getItems());
```

The second tag mytag.process reads the list of items from pageContext and processes them.

```
List allItems = (List)pageContext.getAttribute("items");
```

I searched a bit on the Internet and saw that Freemarker has the Object Wrapper feature to wrap the objects that are put to pageContext and convert them to SimpleHash, SimpleSequence and SimpleCollection types in order to make them easily accessible by the templating code. This is explained in the http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_objectWrapper.html

I am not allowed to modify the taglib to not to cast "items" to java.util.List.

Is there a way to tell Freemarker not to convert java.util.List to its SimpleSequence object?

Thanks..

Comment: From that link you gave - Use an `ObjectWrapper.BEANS_WRAPPER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Before 2.3.22**: Ugh... that's kind of broken really. It should give you back the original object. But looking at the source code, that only works if you are using a pure `BeansWrapper` as the `objectWrapper` (or some custom subclass of it that still returns things wrapped into an `AdapterTemplateModel` or `WrapperTemplateModel`, so that FreeMarker can extract the original object).

**Update (since 2.3.22):**

This is fixed in FreeMarker 2.3.22, but as fixing this is not 100% backward compatible (only 99.99% or like...) you have to activate the fix:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>incompatible_improvements</param-name>
    <param-value>2.3.22</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This works with `DefaultObjectWrapper` too, so you shouldn't change the object wrapper from its default. `DefaultObjectWrapper` with 2.3.22 improvements activated pretty much deprecates pure `BeansWrapper` anyway.

Alternatively, you can activate 2.3.22 fixes only for the object wrapper (as opposed to the whole `Configuration` above):

```
<servlet>
  ...
  <servlet-class>freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet</servlet-class>
  ...
  <init-param>
      <param-name>object_wrapper</param-name>
      <param-value>DefaultObjectWrapper(2.3.22)</param-value>
  </init-param>
  ...
```

Comment: BTW, I will try to fix this in 2.3.22 (not yet scheduled). The obstacle used to be backward compatibility, but we will see. If noting else, then with `incompatible_improvements` set to `2.3.22` it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.

I think there may be a bug in the FreemarkerServlet because when I tried to set BeansWrapper in the overridden init method like below, it has no effect and it uses the DefaultWrapper.

```
public void init() throws ServletException { 
   super.init(); 
   Configuration cfg = getConfiguration(); 
   cfg.setTemplateLoader(new CustomPageTemplateLoader()); 
   cfg.setLocalizedLookup(false); 
   cfg.setObjectWrapper(ObjectWrapper.BEANS_WRAPPER); 
}
```

But when I return the ObjectWrapper in the overridden createObjectWrapper method, it worked.

```
@Override
protected ObjectWrapper createObjectWrapper() {
    return ObjectWrapper.BEANS_WRAPPER;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, apparently, the author has only expected the `protected` methods to be overridden (like in your 2nd variation), which is fine, but he failed to make the other methods `final`. Consider them to be `final`. (: But, most importantly, you don't need to override any classes for this; see my updated answer.

Comment: Furthermore, if you just want to change what the **default** object wrapper is (i.e., when there's no `object_wrapper` `init-param` specified), starting from 2.3.22 you should override `createDefaultObjectWrapper()`.